# Systimebrn.exe using high CPU

Tags: windows-8.1

I have my machine running on Win 8.1 and sometimes I notice that my machine has a very high CPU usage when it is just idle. In the taskmanager I can see that this is caused by a process called `systimebrn.exe`, which can sometimes take up to 20% of my CPU (Intel Core i7-4800MQ).

[image: CPU usage systimebrn.exe]

Does anybody here can provide me the following information:

1 What is this process doing? Strolling around the internet did not provide me any details on this process.

- Based on the information in the services.msc I do not get any much more information than that it is a `System time application manager`

2 Why is this process using so much of my CPU? As I can not see that a system time application should ever use that much CPU power.

Answer (score 1):

This .exe can be found in Task Scheduler and the verification signature is from Mandiant, an AntiVirus service. That explains the heavy CPU usage.

You should be able to find this process/executable by looking in Services or TaskScheduler which can be run by executing the following run commands. `Services.msc` & `taskschd.msc`. Both should provide more details in terms of notes, location, triggers, etc..

Comment: I am not running any Mandient software

Comment: Did you even try looking in `Services.msc` or `taskschd.msc` like suggested? You may not knowingly be running mandiant software but you could easily be running a program that uses a tool or service they provide. Either way, your questions have been answered. If you don't want it running, find it on your system, figure out what it's doing/where it's coming from. If it's a part of a program you want, keep it. If not, remove it. In any case, all of those things can be done in services, taskscheduler, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like it's made by Mandient/FireEye. Are you running one of their products? Wasn't familiar with them, but their site says they offer cyber security services. I'd assume it's one of their scanners or tools running.

If you want to dig deeper, you can check out the process tree, related services, file locations, etc. Here's a [bunch of info](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-view-manage-running-processes-windows-8-task-manager) for that on Win8.1.

Comment: I am not running any Mandient software